# How to understand mapping function of kernel?

Tags: machine-learning, kernel-trick

For a kernel function, we have two conditions one is that it should be symmetric which is easy to understand intuitively because dot products are symmetric as well and our kernel should also follow this. The other condition is given below

> There exists a map $φ:R^d→H$ called kernel feature map into some high dimensional feature space $H$ such that $∀x,x′$ in $R^d:k(x,x′) \ = \ <φ(x),φ(x′)>$

I understand that this means that there should exist a feature map that will project the data from low dimension to any high dimension $D$ and kernel function will take the dot product in that space.

For example, the Euclidean distance is given as

$d(x,y)=\sum_{i}(x_i-y_i)^2= <x,x>+<y,y>-2<x,y>$

If I look this in terms of second condition how do we know that doesn't exist any feature map for euclidean distance? What exactly are we looking in feature maps mathematically?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/127366/755, https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/472829/2921, https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/21994/1794.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 1):

To check if the kernel $K$ (feature map function) is a valid kernel or not, $K$ must satisfying [Mercer's condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercer%27s_theorem#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20specifically%20functional%20analysis,Mercer%20(1883%E2%80%931932).).

**Mercer's condition**: The kenel $K$, is a valid kernel if and only if  $K$ is **positive definite**.

This satisifed in case of there's a matrix $c$ such that

$M$ = $c^T K c$, where $K$ is the **Gram matrix** (Kernel resultant matrix).

$st:$ $M \geq 0, for \,\, all \,\, real \,\ value \,\ c_i$

Or

$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n} c_i k_i{_j} c_j \geq 0 $

$\geq 0$ $\Leftrightarrow$ **positive semi-definite**

before going to the intuition of why using **Mercer's condition** & **intuitive proof**, I would like to mention that, check the existence of the kernel $K$ and **Mercer's condition** has nothing to do with feature map itself, however it's a crucial for the **convergence** of the **quadratic program** such (**SVM**), or more generally the **convexity**.

---

### Intuition

$K$ is a **symmetric** matrix  then by the [spectral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem) $K$ is a **diagonalizable** matrix (in other words, we can decompose it), so we can reformulate K by [eigendecomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix)

$K = VDV^T$

where $V$ is an **orthogonal** matrix and its column are the eigenvectors, and $D$ is a **diagonal** matrix with eigenvalues $λ_i{_j}$ on the diagonal.

If : $\exists $ $λ_i{_j}$ $for \,\, all \,\, i=j$ $such \ that \ λ_i{_j} < 0$

($\exists $) $\Leftrightarrow$ There's exist

Then the kernel $K$ not a valid kernel, beacuse of the **negative** eigenvalue means, there's a such point at which the **Hessian** is indefinite, in other words, the critical  point is a saddle (the function is strongly convex-concave), then the primal problem has no solution, and even dual problem could be very expensive to compute (arbitrarily large).

by [Sylvester's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion), $K$ has negative eigenvalues if and only if it is not **positive semi-definite**.

---

### Geometric intuition

The feature mapping by kenel function or the **inner product** of the features vector (row matrix) $x_i$ , $x_j$, $K=\langle \phi(x_i)\,, \phi(x_j)\rangle$ is same as the mesurement of the **similarity** of two functions by the definition of [Hilbert space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space) concept, visually, the kernel function is a congruent transformation, which is a transformation in an isometric space, if we have a negative eigenvalue, then transformation has occurred in the opposite direction in **isometric space**, in other words, the image reflecte across some axis.

Comment: Nice explanation, Computing Kernel Matrices for all of the space for example in the euclidean distance just to check whether it's valid or not would be a very difficult and time-consuming task. What do you recommend in that scenario? How should one approach to formal proofing then?

Comment: Euclidean distance isn't a valid kernel function, as $K$ is not positive semi-definite and by Sylvester's criterion, we have nothing to check, otherwise you may use **Sylvester's criterion**

Comment: For SVM for example, it's commonly used RBF kernel, the polynomial kernel as those kernels satisfies Mercer's condition, in machine learning the kernel valid if and only if it's always valid for all possible random variable X, not only for the training set.

Comment: Depend on your use case the best thing to do so, is to use the popular kernel function, or **Sylvester's criterion**.

Comment: okay, thanks! for Sylvester criterion, I have to first verify positive definiteness right then i will be able to apply it?

Comment: Yeah, check the positive definiteness and then the factorization if there's exist $B$ such that $A=B^TB$ and $B$ is nonsingular then all eigenvalues are positive (kernel is valid), you also could check this text book page 558

http://www.cse.zju.edu.cn/eclass/attachments/2015-10/01-1446085870-145420.pdf

Comment: I think one should state clearly that it is in general NOT enough to check positive definiteness of specific matrices. You need to ensure positive definiteness for ALL possible matrices from points of the input space. By checking specific matrices you can only rule out certain symmetric functions as NOT being kernels. That said for special classes exist theorems e.g. Bochner´s theorem for translation invariant kernels [here](http://gpss.cc/gpss13/assets/Sheffield-GPSS2013-Durrande.pdf) pg15 and there are ways of making new kernels from known ones (pg22)

Comment: Sure, you are right, I have mentioned that at 2nd and 3rd comments, but even though, we can randomly check about 10000 examples of input space for approximation, in practice, it's a reasonable assumption, because of the limitations of the input space (population in statistics). you can check the logistic growth by Verhulst.

Comment: You will never be able to check the definiteness and factorization of all possible matrices, as Mercer's condition input space is the all real numbers (infinite combinations).